# Android cant execute Http get or post request

Tags: android

I am trying to excute very simple example from one of tutorial on the Internet. But can'nt execute. It gives me exception on sending the http get request to server....the code runs fine untill it reaches at sending the request to server.

**HttpExample Class:**

```
    public class HttpExample extends Activity {

        TextView httpStuff;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
            httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
            GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
            String returned;
            try {
                returned = test.getInternetData();
                httpStuff.setText(returned);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

        public class GetMethodEx {

            public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
                BufferedReader in = null;
                String data = null;
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    URI website = new URI("http://www.mybringback.com/");
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    request.setURI(website);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    // Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "Here",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                            .getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String l = "";
                    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(l + nl);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    data = sb.toString();
                    return data;
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                            return data;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**Android Manifest.xml**: I have also enable the Internet permission

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.httpclient"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.httpclient.HttpExample"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I dont know whats the problem because i have run so many other codes to send or recieve data from the server but they also dont execute may be its the problem with emulator or something... plz guide me on this  Here's the class code and manifest......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Option 1 is only good to test it. But you should avoid using this method for real and make an `AsyncTask` for it

//===========================================================================
 Option 2:

Used this tutorial to make a proper ASyncTask: http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/android/SimpleHttpGetThread.html

//===========================================================================
 Used ASyncTask as final (option 2).

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat output, it says **`NetworkOnMainThreadException`**, means that you are doing long running task (web call) on main thread directly.

For implementing such long running task, you can either implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or Threading implementation for making web call.

FYI, AsyncTask is known as Painless Threading, means that you don't need to bother about any threading process.

Implement your web call inside one of the method `doInBackground()`, one example is already given on the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

check connect from your device with internet.

if you settext for textview, try download simple text : http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265